# Where does GHC allocate foreign memory and how does the garbage collector treat it?

Tags: haskell, memory-management, garbage-collection, ghc

This question is about the functions [`alloca`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Foreign-Marshal-Alloc.html#v:alloca) and [`malloc`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Foreign-Marshal-Alloc.html#v:malloc) from [`Foreign.Marshal.Alloc`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Foreign-Marshal-Alloc.html) and [`newForeignPtr`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Foreign-ForeignPtr.html#v:newForeignPtr) and [`mallocForeignPtr`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Foreign-ForeignPtr.html#v:mallocForeignPtr) from [`Foreign.ForeignPtr`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Foreign-ForeignPtr.html). Where does the allocated memory live and how does the garbage collector treat it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`malloc` calls the C `malloc()`, so it allocates memory on the C heap which you have to free manually. (You can also do that from C with `free()` if you like.)

`alloca` and `mallocForeignPtr` allocate pinned byte arrays, which live on the Haskell pinned heap. The GC will free these automatically when they're no longer needed, but will never move them (since they're pinned) so you can pass their addresses to a C function.

`newForeignPtr` doesn't seem relevant to your question.

Answer (score 6):

The memory pointed to by `Ptr a` allocated by `malloc` lives on the heap, as in the C programming language. It is ignored by the garbage collector - you have to manually deallocate it yourself using `free`, and be careful to never use it again after that.

`alloca f` does a similar allocation, call `f` with the pointer, and free the memory after that. The pointer must not be used after `f` returns.

These routines are not meant to be used in everyday code, but only to interface with other languages, using a C-like interface (FFI). You get precisely the same memory safety guarantees C offers -- which means practically none. As such it is quite dangerous, and should be used with great care.

By comparison, the `ForeignPtr`-pointed memory still lives on the heap, but will be garbage collected after no more pointers (i.e. Haskell's `ForeignPtr a`) refer to the memory. Note that, even if garbage collection is used here, this kind of pointers are not risk-free. Indeed, when Haskell has no more live pointers to the memory the runtime will free it, even if that pointer is still live in the foreign language. The programmer must ensure that this will never happen.

Comment: The `ForeignPtr` stuff looks substantially nicer (it frees memory automatically).

Comment: Although I imagine that you probably can't use it for foreign pointers to foreign pointers....

Comment: Indeed, `malloc` and friends require `Storable a`, so the best you can do is foreign pointers to regular pointers (for which there might be a foreign pointer floating around).

Answer (score 1):

All allocate dynamic memory and it is on the heap.

The odd one is `malloc`; the memory allocated by malloc needs to be EXPLICITELY deallocated.

`alloca` allocates temporary dynamic memory and passes it to a computation. the memory is automatically deallocated when computation has ended.

`mallocForeignPtr` allocates memory and returns a foreign pointer. The memory is deallocated automatically when the pointer is discarded.

`newForeignPtr` adds new reference to an existing dynamically allocated memory. The memory would be deallocated ONLY when the LAST reference to the object is being dropped.

*If you know C++: `malloc` is the naked `new`, `malloca` is the `unique_ptr/auto_ptr`, `mallocForeignPtr` and `newForeignPtr` are `shared_ptr`.*